# Error al exportar base de datos phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

intento exportar mi base de datos de PhpMyAdmin pero no logro hacerlo al momento de descargar la base de datos
me sale "Error:Error de red" reviso si tengo algun problema en la red pero todo funciona bien y al parecer todo funciona bien en el XAMPP que es la plataforma que utilizo para gestionar mi trabajo.

Comment: Por favor, muestra el error, y revisa el log error de phpmyadmin o apache.

Comment: Si no te deja descargar desde la interfaz que es phpmyadmin, quizas puedas hacerlo desde la consola si estas trabajando en Windows,  utiliza linea de comando (cmd) tienes que llegar a la carpeta bin para mayor seguridad y que no tengas problemas de donde la descarga, y aquí utilizas este comando: mysqldump -u root -p nombre_de_la_bd > nombre_a_guardar_la_base.sql  , root puede ser sustituido por otro usuario que tenga todos los privilegios. Saludos

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo !! Pudiste solucionarlo? estoy algo desesperado. Este es el error: *No se pudo guardar C:\Users\user_name_\Downloads\QbDWw3R7.sql.part porque fue imposible leer el archivo origen.
Inténtalo más tarde, o pónte en contacto con el administrador del servidor.*

Comment: Mismo error. Ultimamente XAMPP me está dando muchos problemas desde perdida de datos Error #1039 (Algo bastante grave y que por suerte tenía respaldos de información) pasando por problemas con los archivos Aria y últimamente este error que me parece increíble, ya que tampoco con herramientas externas como Navicat o Worckbench permite la exportación; Uso la última versión de XAMPP con php 8.1.5 y lamentablemente de momento no hay información y no sé que están haciendo los desarrolladores, pero cada versión de XAMPP va peor por cierto la respuesta de @Cesarin me funciono afortunadamente y a part

Comment: he revisado los log, y ninguno me muestra nada para ser honesto

Answer (score 2):

Si la ***base de datos*** tiene ***contraseña***

```
mysqldump -u root -p nombre base de datos > nombre base de datos.sql
```

Si la ***base de datos*** no tiene ***contraseña***

```
mysqldump -u root nombre base de datos > nombre base de datos.sql
```

Buscar el archivo ***xxx.sql*** en ***la carpeta bin***

Answer (score 0):

Si no te deja descargar desde la interfaz grafica phpmyadmin, quizás puedas hacerlo desde la consola si estas trabajando en Windows, utiliza linea de comando (cmd) tienes que llegar a la carpeta bin de mysql para mayor seguridad y que no tengas problemas después de ubicar la ruta donde la guarde.

Ya que estés en la carpeta BIN utilizas este comando:`mysqldump -u root -p nombre_de_la_bd > nombre_a_guardar_la_base.sql`  , root puede ser sustituido por otro usuario que tenga todos los privilegios.

Saludos

Comment: vale, voy a intentarlo tambien

Answer (score 0):

Yo estaba presentando ese mismo error, por lo que investigando pude encontrar que esta versión de phpMyAdmin funciona: [phpMyAdmin 5.1](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/#snapshot_5.1+snapshot)

También te dejo el foro donde lo leí: [Foro](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/17447)

Uso la versión 8.1.4 de PHP.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por comentar, voy a probar la mayoria de soluciones

Answer (score 0):

La versión de phpMyAdmin es la que pareciera no ser compatible con algo de tu PC por ello te recomiendo usar la version https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/#snapshot_5.1+snapshot
[PhpMyAdmin 5.1](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/#snapshot_5.1+snapshot)

Comment: ¿En que se diferencia esta respuesta de la que hizo @mechavarria hace ya tiempo atrás?.